# SQL: minimal date when year is zero

Tags: sql, oracle, min, to-date

I have a table which is something like this

```
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|   year   |   month   |    day    |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|0         |1          |1          |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|2100      |5          |6          |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
|5         |7          |8          |
|----------|-----------|-----------|
```

and I want to select the minimal date. So far I have used

```
SELECT  min(TO_DATE(year ||'.'|| month||'.'|| day, 'YYYY.MM.DD'))
FROM    date_table;
```

which should return

```
01.01.0000 00:00:00
```

The problem is that `TO_DATE` does not accept a year which is equal to zero. How can I circumvent this?

I am using Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a date, you can use some expression and `LPAD` function as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(LPAD(YEAR,4,'0') || LPAD(MONTH,2,'0') || LPAD(DATE,2,'0')) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

**Note**: Oracle does not support the 0000 as a year. it is represented in AD and BC format. so 0001BC is considered as 1 year before 0001AD which is 0000. so (Year 0000 = 0001BC)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and limit to one row:

```
select t.*
from t
order by year, month, day
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This works in Oracle 12C+.  In older versions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by year, month, day
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```